# Assistance with CSS sprite sheet animation

Tags: javascript, css

I have a sprite sheet that is 5760 px width by 5400 px height containing 10 rows and 6 columns each being 960 px width by 540 px height. All of the sprites in the sprite sheet are arranged from left to right and from top to bottom. I wanted to play the 60 images as an animation perhaps using CSS but I am having trouble understand what code is needed. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: All you have to do is to manipulate the `background-position`. Did you googled anything?

Comment: I have been googling for over a week trying to see how others created animations from sprite sheets using CSS but for some reason I couldn't get it to work with my png file. I also can't find anyone using the CSS animation using a grid sprite sheet. Most people are using a sprite sheet as a single row or column and not a grid.

Comment: I have implemented a similar thing here: http://templates.newsoftdemo.info/steps-animation

Comment: Do by any chance have the CSS file for that animation posted somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution to this is to assiocate the background-position changes with css classes in order.

ie.

```
.class1{background-position:0,0} // top left
.class2{background-position:-960px, 0} // indent by 960
// go to .class6 minus 960 to first px value
.class7{background-position:0,540px} // got to left of 2nd row 
.class8{background-position:-960px,-540px} // got to left of 2nd row
// keep going for 10 rows, minus 540 per row and 960 per col
```

then in the javascript (with jQuery)

```
var viewarea = documentGetElementByID('my_window'); // id of DIV
var counter = 0; 
var speed = 300; // miliseconds between frame change

function loopAnimation(){
  // remove old frame
  if($(viewarea).hasClass("class"+counter){
     $(viewarea).removeClass("class"+counter);
  {
  // change counter
  if(counter == 60 ){
     counter = ;
  }else {
  counter++;
  }   
  // move to next frame
  $(viewarea).addClass("class"+counter);
  // set animation to do another frame
  var t = setTimeout(function(){loopAnimation();}, speed);
}
// begin animation
loopAnimation();
```